# HC06 issue after setting the baud rate to 230400 by mistake, it can't communicate to the arduino now

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, serial-port, uart

I tried to set the baud rate of my bluetooth module HC06 to 115200, but I set it to 230400 by mistake!!!
My question is: is there a way to reset the module's baud rate to its default(9600)??? or is there an Arduino code that allows the serial communication at 230400 baud rate???
Please help me, I need help, I'm gonna loose my module

Comment: Hold the main MCU in reset, connect the TX/RX lines backwards, and tell your comm software to use 230400.

Comment: Sorry, but... if you write `Serial.begin(230400);` doesn't it work? You won't get exactly 230400 b/s, but IMHO you will get close enough to be able to reset the baud rate...

Comment: I tried the Serial.begin(230400) with no positive results, please help me guys :(